# FileOutputStream max_allowed_dequeued_buffers 3

Tags: java, android, buffer, fileoutputstream

When I'm trying to use `FileOutputStream` to write data to a file, I get this error and I do not know what to do with it. Here is the `class` where the error comes from. Adding the rest of the program to show what calls `process` would be too long to fit here.

```
public class WriterProcessor implements AudioProcessor {
    File output;
    TarsosDSPAudioFormat audioFormat;
    FileOutputStream fos;

    /**
     *
     * @param audioFormat which this processor is attached to
     * @param output randomaccessfile of the output file
     */
    public WriterProcessor(TarsosDSPAudioFormat audioFormat,File output){
        this.output=output;
        this.audioFormat=audioFormat;
        deleteFile();
        openFileStream();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean process(AudioEvent audioEvent) {
        writeIntoOutputfile(audioEvent.getByteBuffer());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void processingFinished() {
        try {
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }

        try {
            System.out.println("Buffer size: " + audioFormat.getFrameSize());
            byte[] bytes = new byte[audioFormat.getFrameSize()];


            RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(output.getPath(), "wr");
            raf.read(bytes, 0 ,audioFormat.getFrameSize());


        } catch (Exception ex){

        }
    }


    /**
     * Writes data into file
     * @param data
     */
    private void writeIntoOutputfile(byte[] data) {
        try {
            fos.write(data);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.w("Audio processor", "failed writing debug data to file");
            throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
        }
    }

    private void openFileStream() {
        fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(output, false);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("AudioRecorder", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void deleteFile(){
        if (output.exists()) {
            output.delete();
        }
    }

}
```

Method **process()** calls out the **writeIntoOutputFile()** and usually this error comes from `IOException`.

```
09-28 13:54:24.564 19533-19731/ E/[EGL-ERROR]: void __egl_platform_dequeue_buffer(egl_surface*):1851: failed to dequeue buffer from native window 0x98965808; err = -19, buf = 0x0,max_allowed_dequeued_buffers 3
09-28 13:54:24.569 19533-19731/com.starmenew.com E/CameraDeviceGLThread-1: Received exception on GL render thread: 
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: makeCurrent: EGL error: 0x300d
        at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.SurfaceTextureRenderer.checkEglError(SurfaceTextureRenderer.java:544)
        at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.SurfaceTextureRenderer.makeCurrent(SurfaceTextureRenderer.java:525)
        at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.SurfaceTextureRenderer.drawIntoSurfaces(SurfaceTextureRenderer.java:745)
        at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.GLThreadManager$1.handleMessage(GLThreadManager.java:105)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Maybe there is a way to free up a `dequed buffer` or I do not really understand this error.

Comment: it seems this exception is not directly thrown by this class (it only throws ioexceptions). where does the buffer in audioEvent come from?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a renderer error while trying to perform a background operation. This is most likely due to your application losing focus (screen lock or display off) while performing this operation.

- If you require your app to keep focus and display on while performing your background operation, try to add wake lock permission. From https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock :

  ```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }
  }
  ```
- If you are trying to perform an asynchronous background operation such as audio processing and data file writing, try [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask):

  ```
  private class WriteIntoOutputfileTask extends AsyncTask <TarsosDSPAudioFormat, File, AudioEvent, Integer, Long> {

      protected Long doInBackground(TarsosDSPAudioFormat audioFormat, File output, AudioEvent audioEvent) {
          long processedFiles = 0;
          publishProgress(0);
          WriterProcessor myWriterProcessor = new WriterProcessor(audioFormat, output);
          myWriterProcessor.process(audioEvent);
          publishProgress(100);
          processedFiles = 1;
          return processedFiles;
      }

      protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
          setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
      }

      protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
          showDialog(result + " streams processed successfully");
      }

  }
  // Then run this code to start the task:
  new WriteIntoOutputfileTask().execute(audioFormat, output, audioEvent);
  ```

This is only a proof of concept, of course. For the actual implementation, you should rewrite your `WriterProcessor` as an `AsyncTask` itself. Your `public boolean process(AudioEvent audioEvent)` method would be then part of the `doInBackground` method of the `AsyncTask` extension.

For more convoluted asynchronous operations you can look into [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService) or [TaskScheduler](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling#js).

If you want your task to be synchronous (from your code it does not seem so), find the alternative that best suites your need from [DownloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager) or [SyncAdapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/)